# Firing event on changing content in div element

Tags: jquery, html, onchange

I have a div with contentediatable set to true

```
<div name="" id="lbl_content_one" contenteditable="true" classref="REF_ONE"></div>
```

I tried with

```
$('[classref="REF_ONE"]').change(function(){
    var elem = $(this); 
    console.log(elem.val())
    if(elem.val() != ""){
        // execute
    }
});
```

But it didnt work. I need to fire an event when user changes the content. Is this possible using jQuery?

Please note that I have several divs with same class and on change of those divs, I need to trigger the event and update the content of divs to backend.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you may use the events: keyup, click....

In pure javascipt, you may use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

> MutationObserver provides developers a way to react to changes in a DOM. It is designed as a replacement for Mutation Events defined in the DOM3 Events specification.

In order to listen for changes in your content editable you have to listen for:

- characterData: Set to true if mutations to target's data are to be observed
- subtree: Set to true if mutations to target and target's descendants are to be observed

The observer must be started when you need and stopped when you have finished:

The snippet:

```js
// Define your handler and config
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    var elem = mutation.target;
    console.log(elem.textContent);
    if(elem.textContent != ""){
      // execute
    }
  });
});
var config = { characterData: true, subtree: true };


// start the observer
observer.observe(document.getElementById('lbl_content_one'), config);

// later, you can stop observing
// observer.disconnect();
```

```css
#lbl_content_one {
   border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
Start writing here:<div name="" id="lbl_content_one" contenteditable="true" classref="REF_ONE"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `.change` event directly work for `contenteditable="true"` `div` but you can achieve it with below steps.

1. Assign HTML of div to a variable `contents`
2. on `blur` event get the div's HTML again and compare it with
   variable `contents`
3. If it differs that means change has occurred in div's HTML and then
   assign the new HTML to the variable `contents` and then now on wards
   that HTML will be compared in on blur events.
4. If it does not differs then no change has made.

Please check below snippet for better understanding.

```js
var contents = $('#lbl_content_one').html();
$('div[classref="REF_ONE"]').on('blur',function(){
    if (contents!=$(this).html()){
        alert('Content changed.');
        contents = $(this).html();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="" id="lbl_content_one" contenteditable="true" classref="REF_ONE">Test</div>
```

Comment: Code without explanation helps no one! Please add an explanation to better this answer

Comment: @AndrewL. Explanation added...

Comment: Please read the explanation and go through the snippet and then read the explanation again you will get clear idea what I am trying to explain. Thanks.

Comment: If there are several divs with the same classref attribute, this will become tricky; which infact is my case

Comment: Does anything in all those divs that make it different?

Comment: If yes then that thing you can use as key ane create an array and store the html in that array with that unique key and use it for comparison..

Answer (score 0):

**Something like this, with an if statement would work:**

```
var content = $('#lbl_content_one').val();
$(document).on('change', '#lbl_content_one', function() {
 new_content = $('#lbl_content_one').val();
 if (new_content == !content) {
  $(this).hide();
 }
});
```

You can change `'change'` with `'keyup'` or `'keydown'` or both aswell.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it for `keyup` and `keydown`. refer the working demo. that will show the user `entered` text for each `keyup` and `keydown`.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

#lbl_content_one{
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 2px solid black;
}

</style>

<body>


<div name="" id="lbl_content_one" contenteditable="true" classref="REF_ONE"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#lbl_content_one").on('keyup keydown',function(){
 var the_text = $(this).text();
 alert(the_text);
});



</script>
</body>

</html>
```